# To find the location of a datapoint without database schema documentation

Tags: informix, cisco-axl

I program for a Linux based appliance (Cisco CUCM) that uses Informix and am working with documentation that, sadly, isn't very helpful (https://developer.cisco.com/media/UCM10.5DataDictionary/UCM10.5DataDictionary.htm) in this particular situation.

Each device configured in the appliance has dozens of settings that are stored in tables.  One setting the appliance calls "Advertise G.722 codec" on the device is no where to be found in the data dictionary and am wondering if there's a way to find it.

I've not really been in this spot before, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ouch!  Only 735 tables listed in the documentation. Is it feasible to take a `dbexport` of one of the databases (it may not be feasible because it locks the database). If it's possible, you my then be able to use `grep` to analyze the unloaded data and find what refers to the G.722 codec. If that's not feasible, it is extremely messy. There are 6 tables in the list that might be related to codecs, judging from their names: `codeclist (1104);
codeclistmember (1105);
destinationcodecontrol (971);
typecodec (1103);
typemohcodec (156);
typesipcodec (205)`.  Maybe not 'destinationcodecontrol'.

Comment: Unfortunately, the CLI limited.  I've looked at some of the tables you suggested, but I'll take a look at all of these and see what I can find.  Thank you for your input, nice to know someone else besides me sees it the same way.

Comment: My suggestion is to ask this question at communities.cisco.com.  You may get an internal answer on building an sql query

Answer (score 1):

This may be a late response for the OP, but this may help others. Device-specific settings are store in XML blob across one or two tables, depending on CUCM version. See https://developer.cisco.com/docs/axl/#!faq/database-tables-1 for detail.

Comment: Hi, Sergey.  Thanks for the reply (albeit a bit late).  I was able to find it eventually but it involved a complex query across tables.